# Python - can't run a function step by step which includes a loop function several times

Tags: python, function, loops

As title, i have problem to use run a function which includes a loop function several times. The reulst is what i want. I tried to solve it by a list for example, Funs_list = [measure("A"), measure("B")], but same result. the loop function will not run step by step every time.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def measure(name):
    global voltage, data

    data = []
    if name == "A":
        voltage = -0.2
        limits = +0.2
    else:
        voltage = -0.1
        limits = +0.1
    def loop():
            global voltage , data
            data.append(round(voltage,3))

            voltage += 0.02

            if voltage > -0.01:
                voltage = 0
                data.append(round(voltage,3))
                root.after_cancel(loop)
                print 'data', data

            else:
                root.after(1000, loop)
    root.after(1, loop)



def others():
    global data

    measure("A")
    A = data
    print 'A', A


    measure("B")
    B = data
    print 'B', B

    print 'i am here'



root = Tk()
root.title("A Tool")
Button(root, text="Test other",width=38, height = 8, bg='gray',command=lambda:others()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When i pushed button 'others, the result is like:

```
    A []
    B []
    i am here
    data [-0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0]
    data [-0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But i want to have result like below which perfrom the function 'others' step by step. What should i do ?

```
    data [-0.2, -0.18, -0.16, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0]
    A [-0.2, -0.18, -0.16, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0]
    data [-0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0]
    B [-0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0.0]
    i am here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it looks like you don't want `measure` to return until after the loop has finished running. If that is the case, you can use tkinter's ability to wait for a variable to be set before continuing.

You might try modifying your code to look like this:

```
def measure(name):
    flag = BooleanVar()
    ...
    def loop():
        ...
        if voltage > -0.01:
            ...
            print 'data', data
            flag.set(True)
        ...
    loop()
    root.wait_variable(1000, loop)
```

With the above, `measure` will not return until the flag is set, and the flag won't be set until the loop completes.

### An event-based solution

Personally I would never do it like that, however. It seems that what you're trying to do is say "do something when the voltage rises above a threshold". A rising voltage can be thought of as just another event, just like clicking a button or typing some text.

If that is the case, you might want to create and bind to *virtual events*.

For example, you might want to create the events `"<<Voltage-A>>"` and `"<<Voltage-B>>"` which represent the A and B voltages rising. You can bind to those events so that when they happen, you do whatever it is you need to do. Also, since you want to measure B only after the voltage on A has risen, you can trigger the measurement of B on the same event.

Here's a somewhat contrived example based on your original code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def measure(name):
    global voltage, data

    data = []

    if name == "A":
        voltage = -0.2
        limits = +0.2
    else:
        voltage = -0.1
        limits = +0.1
    def loop():
            global voltage , data
            data.append(round(voltage,3))

            voltage += 0.02

            if voltage > -0.01:
                voltage = 0
                data.append(round(voltage,3))
                root.after_cancel(loop)
                event_name = "<<Voltage-%s>>" % name
                print 'data', data
                root.event_generate(event_name)

            else:
                root.after(1000, loop)

    loop()

def print_data(name):
    global data
    print name, data

root = Tk()
root.title("A Tool")
Button(root, text="Test other",width=38, height = 8, bg='gray',command=lambda:measure("A")).pack()

root.bind("<<Voltage-A>>", lambda event: (print_data("A"), measure('B')))
root.bind("<<Voltage-B>>", lambda event: print_data("B"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks very much. the second solution is prefect. :)

Answer (score 0):

I m no expert in `Tkinter` but the problem here is bad usage of `root.after()`.

Your function `measure()` have already returned and printed A, but because `root.after()` still haven't been called yet because it has to wait some ms, you get empty table. Then after those ms pass, your data is updated, but eveything what you would expect to be done is already over.

I have changed your code a little:

```
def measure(name):
    ...
    def loop():
            ...

            if voltage > -0.01:
                voltage = 0
                data.append(round(voltage,3))

                print ('data', data)
                return  # root.after_cancel(loop)

            else:
                loop()  # root.after(1, loop)

    loop()  # root.after(1, loop)
```

and here is my result:

`data [-0.2, -0.18, -0.16, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0]
A [-0.2, -0.18, -0.16, -0.14, -0.12, -0.1, -0.08, -0.06, -0.04, -0.02, 0]`

Comment: Hi Lucasz, thanks for your help. Yes, the output is correct and perfect. but if i integrated the code with Tkinter, it will cause button frozen which means after i push the button, the button will keep downside and will go up once the code runs to end. Actually, i need time about 10seconds after the line 'data.append(round(voltage,3))' to do something else. The button frozen will cause the whole window looking urgly. If i use root.after command, there is not button frozen issue but the output has problem as i wrote.

Comment: You will need to rethink logic of your code then. It is impossible to get result you want like this. Try putting calculation in a diffrent thread, or create class with object where data is stored as variable and it get printed after it got updated with calculation.